# What is the highest post-doctoral salary one should ask for (immunology)

Tags: job-search, postdocs, united-states, salary

I know the average salary is generally 45K USD for science post-docs. However, I received an email from a team of researchers who I had an excellent interview with and basically asked, "How much do you want?"

I have no idea what is the maximum amount of money I should ask for without being insulting. I'll be honest, although I don't do science for the money, this would definitely help make a decision for this particular posting.

Comment: What country is the position in?

Comment: ahh sorry. NY - USA

Comment: NY city or NY state? Living expense is high in NY city.

Comment: Have you asked them what their budget is? (it's not always easy to ask, and can come across badly if you phrase it wrongly, but it's a number that's worth knowing, in such negotiations)

Comment: In my field (mathematics), one of our major professional societies conducts salary surveys, which are very helpful for getting an idea of a reasonable range.  You might see if your field has something similar.  As another possibility, public universities often publish all their salary figures.

Comment: Another question is whether this is a 9-month or 12-month salary, and if the former, what are the prospects for summer support.

Comment: 12 month - NY upstate. Budget is huge.

Comment: pure pen and paper mathematics, or with a *pinch* of computer simulation and software development ? Do you have to sign off NDAs ? do you expect part of your research to remain unpublished ?

Comment: What field is this in? Do you have a family/children? Is medical insurance included?

Answer (score 2):

Postdoc salaries as high as 60K are not unheard of, especially if the cost of living is high and/or you have children. I believe some very competitive "independent postdoc" positions can even reach as high as 70K. However, these salaries may not increase annually, while typically lower salaries do increase annually.

BTW I believe the average 1st year postdoc salary is under 40K (and so is the NIH postdoc salary guideline).